# How to compress a field in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is the configuration of my MongoDB :

```
systemLog:
  path: "C:\\log\\mg.log"
  logAppend: true
  destination: file
storage:
  dbPath: "c:\\data"
  directoryPerDB: true
  engine: wiredTiger
  wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
      cacheSizeGB: 1
```

I want to create a collection that will mainly store "cached" data (response from the google maps API server). How can I Instruct the MongoDB engine to compress one particular field of a document?

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of this being a feature of MongoDB. Per https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/new-compression-options-mongodb-30 you can compress the entire collection.